# Alembic, how do you change the name of the revision database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am working with alembic and it automatically creates a table called `alembic_revision` on your database.  How, do I specify the name of this table instead of using the default name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you run your init. Open the `env.py` file and update `context.configure`, add `version_table='alembic_version_your_name` as a kwarg.